# ./configure checking whether vs checking if

Tags: gnu, autotools, autoconf

`./configure` [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) outputs `checking if` and `checking whether` on execution

how the two results are different for checking conditions?

Comment: `autoconf` will by default create a `configure` script that says `checking whether...`.  If a script says `checking if ...` then that's probably the developer's own words (there are 5 `checking if` when compiling `bash` for example, all from custom test macros). Are you referring to a specific project's `configure` script?

Comment: no, i see this very often in `./configure` script outputs of many common project (when compiling their source)

Comment: oh, so it is a good identification (hint) for custom macros (as introduced by the developer - and not by `autoconf` - as it would always choose the `whether` keyword for checking any kinds of conditions, instead of the 'custom' `if` keyword)?

Comment: i initially thought `whether` may refer exclusively to boolean conditions (with two possible conditional values - true or false), and `if` is used for any other checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `configure` script will most often use the wording `checking whether` because this is the default wording in the default `autoconf` macros.

If a project's `configure` script says `checking if`, then this means the same thing and is probably produced by a custom test macro that the developers have written themselves (or borrowed).

As an example, when configuring `bash` 5.0.7 on my machine, I get 44 `checking whether` and only 5 `checking if`.  The `checking if` mostly come from custom test macros.

```
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking if dup2 fails to clear the close-on-exec flag... no
checking if opendir() opens non-directories... no
checking if getcwd() will dynamically allocate memory with 0 size... yes
checking if signal handlers must be reinstalled when invoked... no
```

([the first one](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/aclocal.m4#n2833) here is actually *not* a macro specific to `bash`, but it's still from the project's [`aclocal.m4`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/aclocal.m4) file)

In a project I'm maintaining for work, in which we mostly use default test macros and macros from [the Autoconf Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/), there are no `checking if` at all, but 65 outputs of the other kind.

At the end of the day, there is no *effective* difference between the two, just as there is no real difference between them in spoken English.